# Load tweets with search term in stead of username

Tags: php, search, twitter, tweets

Now I load the tweets from twitter by using a username like this: (keys and tokens are filled in my code)

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once("twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php"); // PATH TO TWITTEROUTH LIBRARY

if(isset($_GET['twitteruser']) && !empty($_GET['twitteruser'])) {
    $twitteruser = $_GET['twitteruser']; // USER
}
$notweets = 60; // NUMBER OF TWEETS

// OAUTH SETTINGS APPLICATION (https://dev.twitter.com/apps/)
$consumerkey = "";
$consumersecret = "";
$accesstoken = "";
$accesstokensecret = "";

function getConnectionWithAccessToken($cons_key, $cons_secret, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret) {
  $connection = new TwitterOAuth($cons_key, $cons_secret, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret);
  return $connection;
}

$connection = getConnectionWithAccessToken($consumerkey, $consumersecret, $accesstoken, $accesstokensecret);

$tweets = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=".$twitteruser."&count=".$notweets);

$data =  json_encode($tweets);

?>
```

As you can see I load the tweets with a username and set the number of tweets. 
Can this easily be changed to load tweets with a search term?

I've search on google but strangely I can't find much.

I've found this in the twitter API but that doesn't seem to work ..

> https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%23freebandnames&since_id=24012619984051000&max_id=250126199840518145&result_type=mixed&count=4

source: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets
(I changed the link to that link)

But I get this output with a var_dump:

> string(319) "{"statuses":[],"search_metadata":{"completed_in":0.004,"max_id":2.50126199841e+17,"max_id_str":"250126199840518145","query":"%23freebandnames","refresh_url":"?since_id=250126199840518145&q=%23freebandnames&result_type=mixed&include_entities=1","count":4,"since_id":2.40126199841e+16,"since_id_str":"24012619984051000"}}".....

Comment: What does Twitter API documentation say?

Comment: Changed post to my findings!

Comment: Here's what the API documentation says: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets - And the first line of your source says: *This deprecated method is replaced by GET search/tweets in API v1.1* - So you're using a deprectaed query, which most likely is why it's not working.

Comment: And how can I change this?

Comment: Seems like you're getting an empty result... Maybe you could try another keyword? Or query the endpoint with less restrictions (e.g. with no `since_id`) just to make sure you get some results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Twitter search API only returns tweets from the past week or so. See more info [here](http://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search).

> The Search API is not complete index of all Tweets, but instead an index of recent Tweets. At the moment that index includes between 6-9 days of Tweets.

Note that the search feature on Twitter's website *does* query historical tweets, it is just the API that does not support them.